# Visual Tabpages

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, tabpage

Hellos guys, I'm trying to create tabpages dinamically everytime I clic a button so the problem is when I limit the creation of a tab that exist already, I tried Controls.Find method and got "Value of type 'Control()' cannot be converted to 'Boolean'"... Here is my code in Visual Studio 2015. I will appreciate any help or another method.

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myTabPage As New TabPage()
    TabControl1.Visible = True

    If myTabPage.Controls.Find("Pedido", True) Then

        TabControl1.SelectedTab = myTabPage

    Else

        Form1.TopLevel = False
        myTabPage.Text = "Pedido" 
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage)
        myTabPage.Controls.Add(Form1)
        TabControl1.SelectedTab = myTabPage
        Form1.Show()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls.Find returns an array of controls, not a boolean.  So do the following:

```
If myTabPage.Controls.Find("Pedido", True).Length > 0 Then
```

**EDIT:**

With the assumption you are trying to either select or create a tab called "Pedido" (and stripping out some of the code for clarity), try the following:

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      TabControl1.Visible = True

      Dim c = TabControl1.Controls.Find("Pedido", True)

      If c.Length > 0 Then
         TabControl1.SelectedTab = CType(c(0), TabPage)
      Else
         Dim myTabPage As New TabPage()
         myTabPage.Text = "Pedido"
         myTabPage.Name = "Pedido"
         TabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage)
         TabControl1.SelectedTab = myTabPage
      End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: For readability, I might suggest: putting `Dim tabExists As Boolean = myTabPage.Controls.Find("Pedido", True) IsNot Nothing` on the line above, and then `If tabExists Then`.

Comment: I tried that but that just give true results for any value disabling "Key" from find method...You know another method for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It doesn't return a single control but [**_an array of controls_**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx), which will never be null. Check `If myTabPage.Controls.Find("Pedido", True).Length > 0 Then` instead.

Comment: @VisualVincent you are correct.  I will update my response.

Comment: Also, you need to assign a Name to the control when you create it.  This Name is used as the key for the Find.

Comment: Ehm great! So i need to assign name to the control now... could you please update my code. Sorry I'm still learing with vb.